# Android "Back" button is not behaving as I think it should

Tags: android

I've read through and tried several of the suggested solutions and nothing seems to work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is some additional information. My Application can go as deep as 4 activities. For example, after launching from the home screen, the user is taken to my applications main menu. From here they can click an options menu to view an about screen that gives them version info etc. My assumption would be if they hit back from the about menu that they would be taken back to my applications main menu. Instead, the app exits and they are taken back to the home screen. Logcat gives the following output:

```
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onCreate 
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onStart 
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onResume
```

** the above is as expected. Now I hit the about activity **

```
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onSaveInstanceState 
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onPause 
D/ABOUT: AboutBroswer::onCreate 
D/ABOUT: AboutBrowser::onStart 
D/ABOUT: AboutBrowser::onResume
```

** now user hits the back button **

```
D/ABOUT: AboutBrowser::onBackPressed 
D/ABOUT: AboutBrowser::onPause 
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onStop 
D/MAIN_BROWSER: MainBrowser::onDestroy
```

** now I'm back at the home screen **

Thanks, BRoid

Comment: Perhaps try to create a minimal example demonstrating this behaviour. Your assumption is correct, there is probably a problem elsewhere and a minimal example would surely help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behavior of Android. But nevertheless you could change it for your application. In order to do that you can override

```
@Override
protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      //do here what you want
   }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_BACK

There you check if the back button was pressed and then you can do whatever you want. But be aware that this might violate Android design rules.

Comment: Are you sure this is intended behavior?  When you start a new activity, the current activity should remain on the activity stack, and you can return to it by pressing the back button (this is my understanding anyhow).

Comment: Yes. I think it depends on how do you start your new activity.

Comment: That is my understanding as well Kevin. My new activity is just started by creating a new Intent and then calling startActivity on that Intent.

Answer (score 0):

How are you launching the new activity?  Are you by chance calling finish() on the current activity before starting the next activity?  That will remove it from the activity stack I believe.

Comment: No I'm not calling finish() anywhere.